# android recyclerview onclick not working for cardview with only button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` having a `cardview` with only a button in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvsearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsuggest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Other Suggested Words"/>    

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And i am trying the following inside my onCreateViewHolder

```
@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardviewsearchsuggested, parent, false);
    SuggestedButton.PersonViewHolder viewHolder = new SuggestedButton.PersonViewHolder(v);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {    
    // do something here    
    }
    return pvh;
}
```

When i try to debug by clicking on the cardview it does not go into the onClick method.

And my viewholder is

```
public static class SuggestedButton extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    Button buttonsuggest;
    SuggestedButton(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvsearch);
        buttonsuggest = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonsuggest);
    }
}
```

Where as if I have a cardview with TextView instead of button it works.

cardview with textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvsearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textsuggest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Other Suggested Words"/>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And my viewholder is:

```
public static class SuggestedButton extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView textsuggest;
        SuggestedButton(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.searchRVAdapter = searchRVAdapter;
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvsearch);
            textsuggest = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textsuggest);
        }
    }
```

and

```
@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardviewsearchsuggested, parent, false);
    SearchSuggestRVAdapter.PersonViewHolder viewHolder = new SearchSuggestRVAdapter.PersonViewHolder(v);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    // do something here

    }
    return pvh;
}
```

the above code works perfectly fine.

**Temporary Solution**

I have to add 20dp margin on left and right of the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvsearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsuggest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Other Suggested Words" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then if i click on the white space (not on the button) the code inside onClick works.

What i was expecting is if i have mentioned onClicklisterner on itemview then any element inside cardview (also including cardview) is clicked it should not matter and onclick should work.

Because when i have multiple textviews inside cardview it does not matter whereever i click on the cardview even on any textview.

BUt in button i think it may be having some inherent way to take the clicks on it as exclusive.

Comment: try this in **onBindViewHolder()** instead onCreateViewHolder()

Comment: i have updated the answer please check..just removed a line from your code nothing else @Santhosh

Comment: @Santhosh Yedidi check my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `android:clickable="false"` to your `Button` because clickable enabled for button by default. so you need to disable the `clickable` property for `Button`. And now `onclick` will work on your `Cardview`

Solution :

```
 <Button
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonsuggest"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Other Suggested Words"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck up why onclick stopped working suddenly.

Comment: but you can use `TextView` instead of `Button`.And upvote to my answer.

Comment: Yes. but its adds the color and feel automatically.

Comment: I just suggested but you can use it if it's need ed for your  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static class SuggestedButton extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    CardView cv;
    Button buttonsuggest;
    SuggestedButton(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvsearch);
        buttonsuggest = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonsuggest);
        cv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

        @Override
        public void (View view) {    
            if (cv == view) {
               // do something here    
               int position=getAdapterPosition();
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: But i am doing the same through the onCreateViewHolder. i.e viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml with below code :

> Use `Button` `android:elevation=" "` lower than `CardView` elivation.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cvsearch"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonsuggest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Other Suggested Words"/>    

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In **RecyclerView** use `clickListner` as inside `onBindViewHolder()` method :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    LoadDataResult listPotn = list.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Call intent or call method of Activity from here.

            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , Excercise.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**or,** By inside `ViewHolder` class as below code :

```
  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView productBtn;

ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    productBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productBtn);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int itemPosition = getLayoutPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemPosition + ":" + String.valueOf(product_name.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

or, as below code :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>    

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {
    private TextView textView;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
   }
  }  
  }
```

Comment: so why it is not working from the onCreateViewHolder

Comment: onCreateViewHolder only creates a new view holder when there are no existing view holders which the RecyclerView. onBindViewHolder is for setting data and listner call @SanthoshYedidi

Comment: If my card view has Textview instead of button the same code works perfectly. I have another cardview with texview and viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener works well. Only problem i am facing is when i use only button

Comment: its means your buttons listner is not calling? @SanthoshYedidi

Comment: i edited my answer try with my code, sure it will work for you @SanthoshYedidi

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line **below line is the culprit** :-

```
  SuggestedButton.PersonViewHolder viewHolder = new SuggestedButton.PersonViewHolder(v);  // remove this line this is the culprit
```

Instead set the onClickListener **directly on the View** :-

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {    
    // do something here    
  }
```

Comment: If my card view has Textview instead of button the same code works perfectly. I have another cardview with texview and viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener works well. Only problem i am facing is when i use only button

Comment: I tried v.setOnClicklistener it didnt work. the code does not run into the onClick mehod

Comment: on which view do you want to exactly set the `onClickListener` ?

Comment: on the cardview.

Comment: i always use click onBindViewHolder or in `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class.. but the above code should also work @SanthoshYedidi

Comment: may be because of your focusability of view..i tried it..it works in my case.. @SanthoshYedidi i set click listener on the view directly..

Comment: Yes when i add margin on left and right 20dp and then i click on the white space instead of the button it works.

Comment: But button is part of the itemview it should not matter whichever space we click

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it by using interface and implement the interface in the parent class .

`public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(int position);
    }`

implement it in your activity or fragment where ever you are using the recycler view. the handle the click event on the parent

Comment: as i mentioned its not the problem with my code for setting onClicklisterner but its the button which by default capture the click exclusively even the onclick is mentioned for the cardview. Please refer the last part of my question